# Reading sample dataset from tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, python-3.8

I'm trying to read cifar-10 dataset from tensorflow_datasets into 4 parts:

train_data: The tensors contain training data image
train_label: A tensor contains training data label

test_data , test_label : The same with training data

This is how I do it :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
train_ , test_= tfds.load('cifar10' , split = ['train' , 'test'] , as_supervised=True , batch_size = -1)
train_data , train_label = train[0] , train[1]
test_data , test_label = test[0] , test[1]
```

It works fine, but I received a warning when I ran the code line :

```
Dataset cifar10 downloaded and prepared to /root/tensorflow_datasets/cifar10/3.0.2. Subsequent calls will reuse this data.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_builder.py:598: get_single_element (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.get_single_element) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.get_single_element()`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/dataset_builder.py:598: get_single_element (from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.get_single_element) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.get_single_element()`.
```

I suspect because I was using `batch_size = -1` but I don't see any update in tf docs so I doubt it.
If it was a recent update, can you suggest to me an alternative way to load the data into 4 files as I mentioned above?
P/s : I receive this warning on Colab Notebook

Comment: You are overreacting, it is just a warning.

Comment: Is it gonna be removed in the later version or what ?

Answer (score 0):

There is some `typo error` in your above code, Please check below corrected code:

```
train_data , train_label = train_[0] , train_[1]
test_data , test_label = test_[0] , test_[1]
```

And the warning you received, will not make any impact on your code further, you can simply ignore those warnings (instructions).